# Format Math Equation (5,343 + 32) Vertically with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I'm trying to format math equations vertically using CSS. For example 5,343 + 32 should be formatted as so:

Line 1: **5,343** (right aligned)

Line 2: **+** (left aligned) **32** (right aligned) --- Note that the plus sign and bottom number are on the same line.

Line 3: **------** (horizontal line)

I've been fooling around with this for the last hour and have had very little luck.

I laid by HTML out like this:

```
<div id="textbox">
<p class="upperNum">5,343</p>
<p class="sign">+</p>
<p class="lowerNum">32</p>
<p class="line"><hr></p>
</div>
```

Comment: well, <br> makes a new line

Comment: Not sure a set of `<p>` tags is the right markup for this...

Comment: Can you be more specific? You can do all sorts of things using css, line-spacing, or you can just have them all separate divs and position them wherever you want. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to format simple math equations vertically, like this: www.math-aids.com/images/Addition-Flash-Cards.png

Comment: I wrote a JavaScript that generates the math problems, I am trying to format the math problems to look like the above image example.

Comment: Added an answer that uses cleaner markup and can be rendered horizontally or stacked by adding/removing a single class. Have a look below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13715125/101869

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## A semantic approach

Here's a semantic approach to marking up an equation that, from the same markup, can be rendered horizontally or vertically by adding a single class. These equations are made up of **numbers**, an **operator**, and an **equals** sign. Here's the markup for an equation:

```
<span class="equation">
  <span class="number">5,343</span>
  <span class="operator">+</span>
  <span class="number">32</span>
  <span class="equals">=</span>
  <span class="number">5,375</span>
</span>
```

That alone renders horizontally:

5,343
    +
    32
    =
    5,375

With a little CSS, we quickly can transform into a stacked layout. We just add a single `stacked` class to the `equation` element:

```
<span class="equation stacked">
  <span class="number">5,343</span>
  <span class="operator">+</span>
  <span class="number">32</span>
  <span class="equals">=</span>
  <span class="number">5,375</span>
</span>
```

The following CSS does the magic:

```
.equation.stacked {
  display: inline-block;
}

.equation.stacked .number {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 1em; /* space for the operator */
  text-align: right;
}

.equation.stacked .operator {
  float: left;
}

.equation.stacked .equals {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This renders like this:

[image: Stacked equation rendering]

Here's a JSBin you can explore: http://jsbin.com/afemaf/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, I like that it can easily be turned into a horizontal problem too!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?: http://jsfiddle.net/PkfAU/2/

[image]

What you would be doing is using divs, because they are better for creating layouts. Paragraphs are also valid, as the other answer points out, but I find it easier to see with divs. In this case you will need a container div, and three horizontal ones, the second of them being also a container.

`.plus` and `.number` are floating inside its container `.second`, because you need them to use the same horizontal space (all floating elements require a wrapper).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">5,343 </div>
    <div class="second">
        <div class="plus">+</div>
        <div class="number">32</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">
        <div class="result">5,375</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:200px;
}

.first,
.second {
    width:200px;
    text-align:right;
    display:table;
}
.plus {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}
.number {
    width:auto;
    float:right;
}
.third {
    width:200px;
    text-align:right;
    border-top:1px solid black;
}​
```

Comment: That's exactly what I mean but it looks like the + sign and 32 aren't on the same line in the example link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be your best bet:

HTML:

```
<div id="textbox">
    <p class="upperNum">5,343</p>
    <p class="lowerNum">
        <span class="operand">32</span>
        <span class="sign">+</span>
    </p>
    <br class="clear" />
    <p class="line"><hr></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#textbox { width: 75px; }
.upperNum { text-align: right; }
.operand { float: right; }
.sign { float: left; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Here's a fiddle that shows this effect also:

http://jsfiddle.net/8CPar/

Here, you can contain the bottom line in a paragraph, then give the operator and operand a separate span container that you can float, giving you the desired effect. Then, you add a "clear break" which clears the float, making the horizontal break show correctly.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are some fine examples here, but I went through with the effort of making a fiddle so might aswell post it.

You just need to ensure that widths and alignments are set correctly and it should work out.

My [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L6EgA/23/).

```
<div id="list">
    <span class="item">5472</span>
    <span class="operator">+</span><span class="item operand">32</span>

    <hr class="divider"/>

    <span class="result">5504</span>
</div>
```

With css

```
.list
{
    width:50px;
}

span
{
    display:block;
    margin-left:20px;
    font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
    width:50px;
}

.operator
{
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    margin-left:0px;
}

.divider
{
    clear:both;
    width:40px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.operand
{
    float:left;
    width:50px;
}
```

I also created an example using `pre`, that uses pre formatted text, so it should still be precise.

Answer (score 0):

Classics,

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .textbox
        {
            width: 100px;
        }
        .upperNum
        {
            text-align: right;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .sign
        {
            float: left;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .lowerNum
        {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .secondline
        {
            clear: both;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="textbox">
        <div class="upperNum">
            5,343
        </div>
        <div class="secondline">
            <div class="sign">
                +
            </div>
            <div class="lowerNum">
                32
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed width is just for test,